# How to use ArrayBuffer on Dart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, encode, arraybuffer, uint8list

I want to make ArrayBuffer from an Integer like this Javascript code below :

```
const hexEncoded = "76e7480b836359dfa28aa59bccf11e824717a2ae9ea5e09947753b6fecf0d3cd";
const arrBuf = new ArrayBuffer(hexEncoded.length/2);
console.log("arrBuf ",arrBuf);
```

it will print out like this image below
[arrBuf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v0U3.png)

i have trying to using Uint8List in Dart, like:

```
 var arrBuf = Uint8List((hexEncodedData.length / 2).ceil());
 print("arrBuf ${arrBuf}");
```

and it just print out like this

arrBuf [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

how can i achive like that js output for ArrayBuffer ?

Comment: see https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/hex-constant.html

Comment: is this same with ArrayBuffer(number) like my question above ?

how to do that with HexCodec ?

Comment: check it's methods: there are only 2 for decoding and 2 for encoding

Comment: "How can I debug print this" is a pretty pointless question. What do you want to *do*? Do you realize that your JS example only prints an empty buffer, just as your Dart example? Do you maybe want your hex-string as bytes?

Comment: @nvoigt i just want to remake this function from JS
```
export function hexDecode(hexEncodedData: string): ArrayBuffer {
  const arrBuf = new ArrayBuffer(hexEncodedData.length/2);
  console.log("hex code length ", hexEncodedData.length/2);
  
  console.log("arrBuf ",arrBuf);
  
  const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrBuf);
  
  for (let i=0; i<hexEncodedData.length/2; ++i) {
    buffer.set([parseInt(hexEncodedData.substr(i*2, 2), 16)], i);
  }

  return arrBuf;
}
```

to dart code

Comment: so did you use `hex` top level value?

Comment: @pskink i have no idea.
just thinking about how to convert that js code to dart

Comment: so what problems do yo have with those two decoding methods? what is unclear?

Comment: any example how to using your suggestion ?

Comment: i know.
but seems its not answer my question.
i just want to create array buffer from a number like that js code.

actually my case is want to implement AES 256 GCM , the frontend is done using react and crypto plugin, and i want to implement in mobile using flutter.

but, thanks for suggest me.

i will dive into cryptography plugin and looking for more resource.

Thank you

Comment: indeed if all zeros (`[0, 0, 0, ...`) are wrong so what do you expect ? `[Ox76, 0xe7, ...]`?